# Winston logger in angular-electron application

Tags: angular, angular6, electron, angular7, angular8

I am working on angular + electron application. I am using angular version 8. I am trying to add logger to my application and for logging on electron part I am trying to use winston logger.

Once I add winston config file in my application I get following errors on npm run build

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/tail-file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston\transports'
```

Even after defining these dependencies in package.json, I am not able to resolve these issues.

How to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These problems are due to corrupt node modules. some forums suggest answer such as mark fs as empty in webpack configurations but that is not a good solution as by making fs as false we are forcefully saying webpack not to use fs which our porject may require in future.

For me this problem was solved by deleting package-lock.json and node module and again installing fresh node modules in open network.